# При сканировании директории на php exec у папок с русским названием теряется последний символ «а»

Tags: php, windows, cmd, exec

Здравствуйте!

Я использую php функцию EXEC для сканирования дерева каталогов.
Операционная система MS Windows 7 x64 RUS.
PHP v5.6, IIS 7.

Вот пример кода:

```
 exec("dir /S /W /B /A:D D:\files  ", $result);
```

Проблема:
Если в конце названия папки есть русский символ «а» - он теряется.
С другими символами этого не происходит, только с символом «а». Остальные русские буквы нормально обрабатываются.

Кто знает с чем это может быть связано и как исправить?

Comment: сравните с выводом просто при выполнении из командной строки

Comment: Сравнил, в командной строке все хорошо, все буквы. Более того, функция shell_exec тоже возвращает корректные названия. Только результат в виде одной строки. Приходится ее разбивать на массив. Пока использую shell_exec, но хочется понять почему exec себя так странно ведет.